# Is there a way to reassign used SSL certificates without restarting the HTTPServer using C++ Poco?

Tags: c++, http, https, webserver, poco

Is it possible to reassign and reload the SSL certificate/private key pair being used by the Poco SSLManager, and have that change reflected on the web browser without needing to restart the HTTPServer?

I know it's possible to do so by updating the context and web socket objects associated with the SSLManager and HTTPServer. Only problem is that this requires restarting the HTTPServer.

Any help is greatly appreciated, even if it's just a nudge in the right direction. And if there's any clarification I can provide, please let me know.